# How to check if a List<T> Index is null

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a method that calculates total amount for each month from the db, as shown.

```
 public static List<Sale> ChartMonthlySalePerYear()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Connection.DatabaseLocationString))
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
            string query = String.Format("SELECT  strftime('%m', SaleDate)  AS  month,  SUM(AmountPaid)  AS  sum_amountpaid   FROM  {0}   WHERE   strftime('%Y', SaleDate)  =  @1  GROUP BY   strftime('%m', SaleDate)  ", Sale.TABLE_NAME);
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@1", Properties.Settings.Default.ChartYearlyDisplay));
            con.Open();
            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var list = new List<Sale>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Sale value = new Sale()
                {
                    Months = reader["month"].ToString(),
                    SUMAmountPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["sum_amountpaid"])
                };
                list.Add(value);
            }
            con.Close();

            return list;

        }
    }
```

And it returns a List like these by months,

- 01     20000.00 (e.g January)
- 02     13000.00 (e.g February)
- 03     10000.00 (e.g March)
- 04     10000.00 (e.g April )
- 05     10000.00 (e.g May )
- 06     20000.00 (e.g June)
- 07     15000.00 (e.g July)
  But there is no sale for the other months yet.

And this is where is use the method.

```
List<Sale> sum = SaleViewModel.ChartMonthlySalePerYear();
                Jan = sum[0].SUMAmountPaid;
                Feb = sum[1].SUMAmountPaid;
                Mar = sum[2].SUMAmountPaid;
                Apr = sum[3].SUMAmountPaid;
                May = sum[4].SUMAmountPaid;
                Jun = sum[5].SUMAmountPaid;
                Jul = sum[6].SUMAmountPaid;
                //For Ausgust
                if (sum[7] != null)
                    Aug = 0;
                else
                    Aug = sum[7].SUMAmountPaid;
                //For September
                if (sum[7] != null)
                    Sep = 0;
                else
                    Sep = sum[7].SUMAmountPaid;
```

My challenge now is, there is no value for Aug & Sep, i want to check first before i give it a default value, but its throwing an Exception.  `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`  For Aug & Sep.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the question, the if condition you put is not working?

Comment: Yeah............

Comment: you don't need to call `Close` there.. your `using` statement should dispose of the instance and close it.  also, your handling of this list is improper. you should not be using index or ElementAt here at all, because you have a `Months` property that should be used for this purpose.

Comment: Okay, Thanks alot for the Info. @BrettCaswell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to check if the index is less than or equal to the list's length before accessing that index to avoid index out of range exceptions:

```
if (sum.Count <= 7) 
   Aug = 0;
else
   Aug = sum[7].SUMAmountPaid;
```

But this won't work like you are expecting if you have holes in your data.  The index of the List isn't going to match the month if you do have holes in the data.  If that is the case, consider using a `Dictionary<int, Sale>()`:

```
var salesByMonth = new Dictionary<int, Sale>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Sale value = new Sale()
    {
        Months = reader["month"].ToString(),
        SUMAmountPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["sum_amountpaid"])
    };
    salesByMonth.Add(int.Parse(value.Months), value);
}
```

And

```
Sale value;
if (salesByMonth.TryGetValue(1, out value))
   Jan = value.SUMAmountPaid;
else
   Jan = 0;

if (salesByMonth.TryGetValue(2, out value))
   Feb = value.SUMAmountPaid;
else
   Feb = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry there no property like Lenght. I have updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Count, not Length.

Comment: @EdPlunkett-- if `sum.Count==7` then `sum[7]` would throw invalid index range since it would have elements 0..6 defined.  Needs to be `Count <= 7` to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using an index approach to this, since your `Sale` type has a `Months` property that is being populated with the `reader["month"]` value. You can determine whether a month exists by using a predicate (`Func<Sale, bool>` delegate).

Using Linq, you can use the predicate with `First` or `FirstOrDefault` to return the first instance that evaluates to `true`.

```
List<Sale> sum = SaleViewModel.ChartMonthlySalePerYear();

Jan = sum.Where((item) => item.Months == 1).Select((item) => item.SUMAmountPaid).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();
Feb = sum.Where((item) => item.Months == 2).Select((item) => item.SUMAmountPaid).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();
Mar = sum.Where((item) => item.Months == 3).Select((item) => item.SUMAmountPaid).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();
Mar = sum.Where((item) => item.Months == 4).Select((item) => item.SUMAmountPaid).DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();
```

or,

```
Jan = sum.Any((item) => item.Months == 1) ? sum.First((item) => item.Months == 1).SUMAmountPaid : 0;
Feb = sum.Any((item) => item.Months == 2) ? sum.First((item) => item.Months == 2).SUMAmountPaid : 0;
Mar = sum.Any((item) => item.Months == 3) ? sum.First((item) => item.Months == 3).SUMAmountPaid : 0;
Apr = sum.Any((item) => item.Months == 4) ? sum.First((item) => item.Months == 4).SUMAmountPaid : 0;
```

### Alternatively

you could just `.ForEach` to iterate through your records and a switch case to map them.

```
List<Sale> sum = SaleViewModel.ChartMonthlySalePerYear()
    .ForEach((item) => {
        switch(item.Months)
        {
            case 1:
                Jan = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 2:
                Feb = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 3:
                Mar = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 4:
                Apr = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 5:
                May = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 6:
                Jun = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 7:
                Jul = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 8:
                Aug = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 9:
                Sept = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 10:
                Oct = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 11:
                Nov = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            case 12:
                Dec = item.SUMAmountPaid;
                break;
            default: //do nothing
                break;
        }
    });
```

Ensuring that `Jan` through `Dec` are `0` by default.

Comment: mapping collections to instances like this generally aren't pretty.  instead of using an anonymous `Action<Sale>` function here, you can define a method call `MapSaleToMonthInstance(Sale item) { ...switch case...}` and simply pass the method to `.ForEach()`... i.e. `.ForEach(MapSaleToMonthInstance)`

Comment: also note, that you don't have to use Linq's `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods for either of these approaches.. they are just a bit easier to do with them; you can also do a `foreach(var item in sum)` loop with the switch case concept.